# UI of Camera app frozen after user presses the "Use Image" button

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

In my camera app, I click a photo and press the use photo button. When the user presses the "Use Photo" button after clicking the photo, the photo gets saved in the photo library(if the user allows the app to) but the CameraView completely freezes. Here are parts of the code that might help:

ContentView:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CameraView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Part of the CameraView:

```swift
extension CameraView {
    class Coordinator : NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: CameraView
        
        init(_ parent: CameraView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            fatalError("Cancel button pressed!")
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
                CustomizeView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the block of code where Use Photo is controlled

```swift
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil) //Where the CameraView freezes after this.
}
```

Comment: What is `CustomizeView`?

Comment: It is the view I want to go to when the user presses Use Image @Asperi

Comment: How do you show UIImagePickerController?

Comment: @SilisAlin I show by using UIViewControllerRepresentatable